# Angular Interface define allowed values for a key

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using **Angular 8**.

I an an interface like

```
export interface MyInterface {
  q: Array<string>;
  filter_by: 'id'|'name'|'data';
}
```

and defining type of dictionary is

```
@Input filterBy: string;

const a:MyInterface = {
  q: ['a', 'b'],
  filter_by: this.filterBy
}
```

But this is giving error as

```
TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"id" | "name" | "data"'.
```

Comment: What is the data type of filter_by ? You meant to have string values

Comment: What are "'id'|'name'|'data'" this anyway,are these user defined datatypes or they are just plain string values?

Comment: @Vinod `'id' | 'name' | 'data'` are strings and are the only possible values for `filter_by`. This is valid as per TypeScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's anything wrong here. Please find the stackBlitz example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ehme3j) with relevant angular version. Error should be somewhere else where you are trying to assign `filter_by` with some non compatible value.

### For updated case, change `filterBy` type from string to

```
@Input filterBy: 'id'|'data'|'name';
```

Comment: Update question with the exactly what I'm doing. I have an `@Input()` parameter of type string which is assigning to the `filter_by` key.

Comment: Thanks, solved it by declaring type of `@Input() filterBy` to `'id'|'name'|'data'`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you used the values instead of datatype in your interface. Change it like this,

```
export interface MyInterface {
  q: Array<string>;
  filter_by: number|string|any;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have ts version higher than 3.4 you can use the following code:

```
const filterProp = 'id' as const
const a:MyInterface = {
  q: ['a', 'b'],
  filter_by: filterProp
}
```

This will prevent string type conversion while variable assigning and it will become typeof 'id', exactly what you need. Here is the docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions